# AdvertisingID changes UUID if I turn "Limit Ad Tracking" on and off again

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to get the `AdvertisingID` of the devices which uses my app. If I turn on the option `Limit Ad Tracking` and immediately on the returning `AdvertisingID` is another although I didn't reset the `AdvertisingIdentifier`.

Is it working correctly? I always read it changes only her ID if I turn on the option `Reset Advertising Identifier` or resetting the whole devices.

My code looks like

```
-(NSString *)getAdvertisingID {
    return [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];
}
```

Comment: your code is correct, but you have to pay attention to the following: if by septa setting the flag to off you have to make sure that your command does not return anything, so as not to violate Apple's policies.

Comment: @WhiteTiger Can you post a url where it is write down? I didn't find anything about that. What do you mean by septa?

Comment: Here a little description of how to activate and deactivate: http://www.imore.com/how-limit-ad-tracking-iphone-and-ipad In the class ASIdentifierManager you can find the advertising Tracking Enabled property that tells you if the flag is on or off, and according to this property (choice made by the user application) you can enable or not the readout to supply then to third parts.

Comment: @WhiteTiger Thx for help

Comment: I hope Essert been helpful